# Using cmake to compare_files with different line endings

Tags: cmake, line-endings

I'm using `cmake` to compare two files like this:

```
cmake -E compare_files file1 file2
```

The trouble is that `file1` and `file2` have different line endings. I'm using `cmake` because I already use that for my build; the above command is in my testing.

I don't need anything special at this point. Just a way to tell the user that the files are different. (Hopefully there are no differences.) If there are differences, I'll just report it at this point and manually inspect more closely.

If there is a convenient way of reporting (e.g., print to screen or write to a file) then I'm open to suggestions on how to make that happen. But I'm really just interested in knowing if there are differences and different line endings are unimportant.

Is there a flag or an option that I'm missing that will ignore the difference in line endings?

Comment: Of all diff utils you chose cmake...

Comment: @texasbruce Well, I'm open to other suggestions, but I'm already using `cmake` and `ctest` so I thought I'd continue using it.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you need to have the output in a cmake context (e.g. collecting information while building a project) or you just need a comparison tool for you to check visually differences? Please be specific on your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

As pointed out by nocnokneo,
as of [CMake 3.14](https://www.kitware.com//cmake-3-14-0-available-for-download/) there is an `--ignore-eol` option, see [merge request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/2778)

**Original answer**

This was an [unsupported feature](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13007) (issue was tracked [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/13007)).

But there's a workaround: you can use [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to create a copy of the files with a uniform row endings before starting the comparison. For example:

```
configure_file(<input> <output> NEWLINE_STYLE CRLF)
```

Note that the option `COPYONLY` is not compatible with `NEWLINE_STYLE`, so you'll have to take care `configure_file` doesn't make any unintended variable substitution.

Comment: I didn't know about that option to configure_file which I'm already using. I'll try it out and let you know how it works.

Comment: This was **exactly** what I needed. I wish I could award you two responses.

Comment: @Jeremy You can still put a bounty! :D :D Glad I could help!

Comment: New issue location: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/13007

Answer (score 1):

With [CMake 3.14](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-3-14-0-available-for-download/) you can now do:

```
cmake -E compare_files --ignore-eol file1 file2
```